# Fail of markdown parser detected if '_ 's are used in a naked URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

In the answer
[realloc() for NUMA Systems using HWLOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933129/realloc-for-numa-systems-using-hwloc/6938825#6938825), the parser breaks my URL link.

The URL was with `__word__`:

> `http://www.open-mpi.de/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.2/group__hwlocality__membinding.php#gade5e2c28ea8475a479bf2b1df36c6ccd`

After parsing, it becomes (`<a href` is broken; no clickable link):

```
hwlocality_membinding.php#gade5e2c28ea8475a479bf2b1df36c6ccd">http://www.open-mpi.de/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.2/group_hwlocality_membinding.php#gade5e2c28ea8475a479bf2b1df36c6ccd
```

Short test:

`http://example.com/_test_` -> `test">http://example.com/test`

Or if I put in a naked URL with `_test_` just here: 
[http://example.com/*test*](http://example.com/_test_)

Comment: So are you *intentionally* not using the markdown syntax for links?

Comment: markdown  is harder, than just putting an url in the text

Comment: And C++ is harder than Java. But at least it doesn't break when you use characters like underscores within the link that have a specific meaning in markdown syntax.

Comment: But naked urls have specific parsing in markdown; and italic will not work in urls, so, I think, parser should not to parse italic in naked urls.

Comment: @Cody If it was just the link not being linkified, I'd agree with you and tell osgx to tough it up. But `">` appearing out of the blue is a different matter; it makes me worry that there might a way to inject arbitrary HTML into the permitted markup (i.e. a security issue).

Comment: @Cody The HTML for the link-not-parsed-as-link is `hwlocality_membinding.php#gade5e2c28ea8475a479bf2b1df36c6ccd">http://www.open-mpi.de/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.2/group_<em>hwlocality</em>_membinding.php#gade5e2c28ea8475a479bf2b1df36c6ccd`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Too much of an edge condition.

Remember that Markdown does not support "naked" URLs officially, so you have your pick of non-naked URLs to use here:

```
<http://example.com/foo__bar__baz#hash>  
<a href="http://example.com/foo__bar__baz#hash">link</a>  
[link](<http://example.com/foo__bar__baz#hash>)
```

http://example.com/foo__bar__baz#hash
[link](http://example.com/foo__bar__baz#hash)
[link](http://example.com/foo__bar__baz#hash)

see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: YouTube [is starting to put underscores in URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117689/168440), so I think we are only going to see an increase in these situations.

Answer (score 7):

This will work correctly from the next build on: [client changeset](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=e316af145b6c3c9721e89dc144d79025a754be0a), [server changeset](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=757c248e2a8f4aa4b89a2fbb206941974534ae09). <s>The underscores will still cause some potentially unwanted styling of the displayed text</s><sup>1</sup>, but the link itself works.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not anymore in most cases (including the one here), thanks to point 2. in [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229236/115866).

Comment: Aaand this broke Github. Probably Github's fault, but `_` is not on the reserved characters list. Can the generated `href` attribute not be normalized? E.g. decode percent-encoded characters for non-reserved characters such as `_`?