# Bug in rendering when answer only contains a link?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fail of markdown parser detected if _ are used in naked url](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100882/fail-of-markdown-parser-detected-if-are-used-in-naked-url)

See this answer: [Grocery CRUD not sorting or searching results and set_model values are not paginated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617044/grocery-crud-not-sorting-or-searching-results-and-set-model-values-are-not-pagin/11674021#11674021)

There appears to be a rendering bug. The answer itself consists only of a single link (it's not a good answer, but that's beside the point). It is incorrectly rendered with `hl_model">` before the link and it appears that the same string has been appended to the end of the link too.

Comment: The underscores are messing it up; open Edit and chop off the `__hl__model` and watch as it magically turns into a proper link

Comment: It had nothing to do with it only being a link, it has to do with a known bug where Markdown still gets processed inside the link. The `__hl__` part was being made into bolded text.

Comment: but should `__hl__model` be there in the first place? (that's the same string that appears broken at the start of the link)

Comment: Found another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681645/powerpoint-interop-api-access-multiple-slide-masters-inside-slide-master-view/11690018#11690018