# Issue parsing link containing _2F00_

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fail of markdown parser detected if '_ 's are used in a naked URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100882/fail-of-markdown-parser-detected-if-s-are-used-in-a-naked-url)

The following link doesn't get parsed correctly.

```
http://weblogs.asp.net/dmckinstry/archive/2006/07/09/Undo-_2F00_-Unlock-for-Others-with-Team-Foundation-Version-Control.aspx
```

**example**

[http://weblogs.asp.net/dmckinstry/archive/2006/07/09/Undo-*2F00*-Unlock-for-Others-with-Team-Foundation-Version-Control.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/dmckinstry/archive/2006/07/09/Undo-_2F00_-Unlock-for-Others-with-Team-Foundation-Version-Control.aspx)