# Bug due to overzealous encoding of URLs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

This link works fine when it's copy/pasted:

```
https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw/
```

But the `_` gets encoded as `%5f` when it's autolinked, and this can break the URL:

https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw/

Edit: Admittedly, the issue is related to GitHub in this case:

```
$ curl -I "https://github.com/cyga/www%5ffdw/"
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 13:42:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Status: 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Length: 226672
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 5062C074:7D81:1D8C557:534BE5AF
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

But Stack Overflow could work around the problem by not encoding the `_` character to begin with.

Comment: No, encoding `_` to `%5f` would not break a URL; it merely uses a standard encoding scheme. The hyperlink *works just fine*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I get a 404 error when I visit the linked page. (Safari on OSX)

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on the hyperlink (Firefox on Windows 7).

Comment: @Bart: I'm merely pasting the URL from the Safari address bar. If I click the resulting link, it's a 404.

Comment: @Denis: it works fine for me in Chrome, but can indeed reproduce the problem in Safari.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: so it is a bug indeed. Perhaps not one that is due to SO itself, but certainly one that SO can work around by not encoding the `_` character.

Comment: This could also be construed as a **Github** problem; they fail to decode the URL encoding correctly, it appears. The URL is certainly *perfectly valid* according to the RFC. Chrome normalizes the URL, heading off the issue.

Comment: To quote the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_unreserved_characters): *URIs that differ only by whether an unreserved character is percent-encoded or appears literally are equivalent by definition*, but it points out some processors may not handle these correctly. `_` is not a reserved character, but my guess is that Stack Exchange escapes it to prevent it from being interpreted as Markdown.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure it's valid per the RFC. What difference does this make if the URL is broken when you try it? I've reported the bug to Github, but I'm sure there are plenty of other sites with the same kind of problems. And the question remains at the end of the day: Is there any good reason for SO to be encoding underscores in URLs like that.

Comment: @Denis: It's a fine line to walk between not triggering a problem and fixing the problem at the source. If sites don't handle percent-encoded characters in the URI correctly then that's a bug with that site. I suspect that the [rewritten markdown emphasis / strong handling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158759/how-to-format-text-containing-underscore-to-italic-style/229236#229236) has something to do with all this.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229144/161198

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fair enough. If even GitHub gets this wrong, then there'll probably be a big bunch of other sites that do as well. And when revisiting, percent-encoding wasn't the optimal solution anyway to fix [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229144/115866).

I'll deploy this right away; change should be available in a couple of minutes.