# Markdown parsing error on link, possibly caused by "-_-"s in URL

Tags: bug, chat, markdown-rendering

A user posted this link in chat:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product

Well, almost; he linked to this: (don't mind the newline I've added for your comparison pleasure)

```
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?
Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product)
```

...but as you can see above, Markdown looks at that couple of `-_-`s and decides that it's actually an attempt to make the link italic.

Attempting to fix the link as such:  (again, ignore the whitespace).

```
[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?
 Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product]
 (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?
  Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product)
```

Results in [this message on chat][1], rendered so: (again, whitespace and HTML comment added for you):

```
<a href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?
         Item=N82E16811119233&amp;cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-%3Ci%3E-11-119-233-%3C/i%3E-Product"
   rel="nofollow">                                      <!--- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑           ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ --->
   http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?
       Item=N82E16811119233&amp;cm_re=Cooler_Ma&zwnj;&#8203;ster_haf_912-<i>-11-119-233-</i>-Produc
</a>
```

It just so happens that the link works anyway, even with the erroneous `<i>` and `</i>`s injected in it.
[1]: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17550794#17550794

Comment: Test: [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product) ← yep, same issue in comments

Comment: Does `<http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_Master_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product>` work? Note the `<`, `>`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not in minim******n: <http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119233&cm_re=Cooler_M‌​aster_haf_912-_-11-119-233-_-Product>

Comment: Interesting, so until `_M` it is a URL, after that everything else is mucked up.

Comment: Related where this was fixed in the full parser: [Fail of markdown parser detected if '\_ 's are used in a naked URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100882)

Comment: @tim except this also happens on non-naked URLs

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that there was one that covered this specific case too (unless there's some subtle difference between comments and chat, in which case sorry, in the middle of party-preparing). :P